# Can A Javascript File Load Itself Asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, squarespace

I use Squarespace as my CMS. I'd like to know if there's a way to have the actual .JS file load itself asynchronously to ultimately reduce the site load time.

For those who don't know, Squarespace gives very limited access to backend content and files. So I'd like to know if there are any alternatives to reduce render-blocking resources.

The file is located in [websitename]/scripts/site-bundle.js found through SFTP.

EDIT: Here's the full code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMKZyQ, as you can see I can't find any script tags to insert the defer or async values.

```
!function(e){function t(o){if(n[o])return n[o].exports;var r=n[o]={exports:{},id:o,loaded:!1};return e[o].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,t),r.loaded=!0,r.exports}var n={};return t.m=e,t.c=n,t.p="",t(0)}([function(e,t,n){e.exports=n(1)},function(e,t,n){"use strict";function o(e){return e&&e.__esModule?e:{default:e}}n(2);var r=n(6),i=o(r),a=n(60),u=n(65),c=o(u),l=n(85),s=o(l);n(86);var d=n(87),f=o(d),p=n(100),h=o(p),v=n(101),y=o(v),m=n(104),A=o(m),g=n(121),b=o(g),w=n(189),_=o(w),x=n(190),E=o(x),k=n(191),S=o(k),T=n(192),L=o(T),O=n(193),M=o(O),P=n(194),j=o(P),C=n(195),R=o(C),I=n(103),F=o(I),V=n(196),N=o(V),D=n(199),B=o(D),G=n(200),U=o(G),H=n(207),z=o(H);i.default.register("AncillaryLayout",f.default),i.default.register("FooterBreakpoints",h.default),i.default.register("HashManager",y.default),i.default.register("IndexFirstSectionHeight",A.default),i.default.register("IndexGallery",b.default),i.default.register("IndexGalleryVideo",_.default),i.default.register("IndexNavigation",E.default),i.default.register("HeaderNavFolderTouch",S.default),i.default.register("HeaderOverlay",L.default),i.default.register("MobileClassname",M.default),i.default.register("MobileOverlayFolders",j.default),i.default.register("MobileOffset",R.default),i.default.register("MobileOverlayToggle",F.default),i.default.register("Parallax",N.default),i.default.register("ScrollIndicator",B.default),i.default.register("SiteLoader",U.default),i.default.register("UserAccountLink",z.default),i.default.register("VideoBackground",function(e){return(0,c.default)(e,function(e){var t=e.handleResize,n=e.handleTweak;(0,s.default)(t,105),a.Tweak.watch("tweak-overlay-parallax-enabled",n)})}),window.addEventListener("controller:refresh",i.default.refresh)},function(e,t,n){n(3).polyfill()},function(e,t,n){(function(t){for(var o=n(4),r="undefined"==typeof window?t:window,i=["moz","webkit"],a="AnimationFrame",u=r["request"+a],c=r["cancel"+a]||r["cancelRequest"+a],l=0;!u&&l<i.length;l++)u=r[i[l]+"Request"+a],c=r[i[l]+"Cancel"+a]||r[i[l]+"CancelRequest"+a];if(!u||!c){var s=0,d=0,f=[],p=1e3/60;u=function(e){if(0===f.length){var t=o(),n=Math.max(0,p-(t-s));s=n+t,setTimeout(function(){var e=f.slice(0);f.length=0;for(var t=0;t<e.length;t++)if(!e[t].cancelled)try{e[t].callback(s)}catch(e){setTimeout(function(){throw e},0)}},Math.round(n))}return f.push({handle:++d,callback:e,cancelled:!1}),d},c=function(e){for(var t=0;t<f.length;t++)f[t].handle===e&&(f[t].cancelled=!0)}}e.exports=function(e){return u.call(r,e)},e.exports.cancel=function()
```

Comment: what would be the improvement? It has to have already been loaded by the browser for it to then be able to instruct the browser to (re)download itself. Alternatively, if you just mean "is there a way for _the browser_ to asynchronously load a JS resource" then sure, the `async` script element attribute has been available for quite a while now.

Comment: also, this is what you give up by using squarspace: you get the convenience of "looks good, easy to make content", and you trade in the power to screw everything up because you had a cool idea that doesn't mesh with how squarespace organises and hosts code and files. That's why they charge you money: if you _really_ want to customize, just pay for the business/commercial plan and you can work with actual html code.

Comment: Will edit the post, yes I'm referring to the browser, how could I add the async attribute to the series of JS functions?

Comment: From what I can see on squarespace, by paying them for the option to work with HTML code, and adding in `<script src="..." async>` yourself. There are some ridiculous things you could do to get around paying, but they'd pretty much guarantee a website that's an even worse loading experience than just being a slow initial load.

Comment: I was just reading about that because I had no idea those plans gave you the ability to work with the HTML code. I'll most likely be going down that route as the money isn't the issue, I'm strictly looking to maximize performance. And thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished for the [Brine/Wright family of templates](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005308187-What-s-my-template-and-its-family-) by doing the following:

1. [Enable Developer Mode](https://developers.squarespace.com/quick-start) (Settings > Advanced > Developer Mode)
2. Using SFTP or Git, obtain access to the template files.
3. Within `site.region` file, change:

   `<squarespace:script src="site-bundle.js" combo="false" />`

   to

   `<squarespace:script src="site-bundle.js" combo="false" async="true"/>`
4. Use SFTP or Git to update your template files on Squarespace's servers.

You may also use `<script src="/scripts/site-bundle.js" async></script>` **instead** of using Squarespace's script loader. Simply replace the aforementioned line in step 3.

As an aside, the unbundled code can be found in Squarespace's [Wright GitHub repository](https://github.com/Squarespace/wright-framework).

For other templates not in the Brine/Wright family, similar steps may apply, though file names may differ.

Comment: That did the trick. The bundle started loading much earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two properties on a `script` tag to do exactly what you want to do:

- specifying `defer` will defer the loading of the script until the page has been fully parsed (and rendered)
- specifying `async` will indicate to the browser that this script can be loaded asynchronously at any point of its choosing.

Those two properties are both well supported ([defer](https://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer), [async](https://caniuse.com/#feat=script-async)) and as such, you can and should make use of them to achieve this.

Comment: Hi Sebastien, I updated the post to include the code. I have no access to the script tags that call on the backend JS files. And the code in the file doesn't use them either.

Comment: Can you put the non-minified version of that? And elaborate further. Is your JS loading *additional* scripts, or are you trying to load that code blob?

Comment: Unfortunately, the source file is already minified. I'm trying to load this specific code blob

Comment: Okay. Now that I fully understand the problem I'm going to craft a solution for you. Since you can't `async` without paying squarespace, I'm going to craft a way to minimize loading time as much as possible.

Comment: That would be great, I'm still doing some research to see if there are any other forms of solutions in the meantime. And thank you, looking forward to the results.